# How do I apply Least Squares to determine the coefficients of a linear time-invariant filter having the desired output?

Tags: fourier-transform, least-squares, parseval

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Consider a linear time-invariant filter with linear phase:
> $$H(e^{j\omega}) = a_0 + \sum_{i = 1}^{N} 2a_k\cos(k\omega)$$
> Determine the coefficients of this filter such that it optimally
> follows
> $$H_d(e^{j\omega}) = \left\{\begin{align}
> 0.2 \quad &|\omega|<\omega_1\\
> 1 \quad &\omega_1<|\omega|<\omega_2 \\
> 0.2 \quad &\omega_2<|\omega|<\pi\\
> \end{align}\right. $$
> in the Least Squares (LS) sense. This is equivalent to minimizing the metric
> $$d(H_d(e^{j\omega}),H(e^{j\omega}))=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|H_d(e^{j\omega})-H(e^{j\omega})|^2d\omega$$Hint:
>
> - Apply the Parseval theorem to get an equivalent statement in the time domain.
> - Write the desired transfer function as a linear combination of ideal low-pass filters.
> - To minimize a convex function, you can differentiate it with respect to the variables and set the derivative equal to zero.

I get stuck pretty much immediately when trying to get the equivalent formulation in the time domain. How do I get the inverse Fourier transform of a sum of N elements? Is it just the sum of the transforms of every term? I can't find any theorem that guarantees it to me.

Comment: "I don't really know how to solve it" is not really enough input for us to be able to help you. You'll understand that we don't do other people's homework. Show us what you did and where you're stuck, and ask a specific question. By the way, the filter is time-INvariant.

Comment: Please see [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Least_Squares_Linear_Phase_FIR_Filter.html#eq:mtxls) and come back if you're still stuck